# I can't see my design view on c#

Tags: c#, webforms, visual-studio-2017

I started working on a c# 2017 project, I closed the file of my program and the next time I opened it this error message showed up, if I try clicking on "omitir y continuar" the desing board is empty. I don't know what to do. If I click on the "iniciar" (start) button the program shows normally. And the line of code that says its wrong is:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

Below is the image of the error.

[image: The image of the error]

Comment: It's hard to understand with this non-english message. It most probably has to do with a messed up designer file, I would guess. Could you delete and regenerate it? Or, your Button is missing. Try to recreate it.

Comment: can you paste your screen capture of *expanded solution explorer*?

Comment: Are you edited `.Designer.cs` file manually? If not, just remove the line that is underlined. Better; just return the previous commit in your version control (if you are not using any version control this is great time to start).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates that you have a registered event for a button that does not exist - you must have deleted `button1` from your form, but never removed its registered event.

You need to open your **Form.Designer.cs file**, where you will see the code line:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

**Remove this line** and compile your project again, or switch to your Design view, which should now be fine.

Comment: this should not cause designer crash?

Comment: @LeiYang Nope. It's a classic case of removing an element and not it's event.

Comment: I had this problem multiple times when working with WinForms, simply taking out the event makes everythings work again. Well, I guess that's the problem with hidden .cs files.

Comment: @IanH. Yeah. MS should really look into the connection between the designer.cs and the form elements, they did a poor job there.

Comment: this will only solve the compiling error, but the VS designer does not necessarily needs fixing this error to launch. so there must be some other root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Name of the reference variable (`button1`) is wrong or name of the method (`button1_Click`). Did you change any of them by your own? You have to chamge it in `*.Designer.cs` file accordingly.